# 3D printer thermocouple noise issues

Tags: analog, thermocouple

I made a post a while ago about having large excursions when reading from my MAX6675. Despite using adum5401 digital isolator to float the MAX6675  as suggested in the original post, I still see a lot of noise on the MAX6675 thermocouple input using a scope.

I did notice on the MAX6675 board there's only one bypass cap on the the VCC rail. There is absolutely no filtering on the thermocouple input.

[Large excursions in thermocouple readings with MAX6675](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274100/large-excursions-in-thermocouple-readings-with-max6675)

Questions:
1) Can I apply some filtering on there?

2) I read on a different forum that the thermocouple amp should ideally be connected to analogue GND and that the AVR microcontrollers don't have any. By using a ADUM5401 to float the MAX6675, have I effectively created an analogue GND? If so, it's still no go.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Thermocouples exhibit extremely low impedance (less than an ohm), so a capacitor simply doesn't do any good. Yes, it acts like a low-pass filter, but (assuming, for instance, a 1 ohm impedance) a 1 uF cap gives a frequency of more than 150 kHz. And thermocouples are actually lower resistance, so the cutoff frequency is even higher, probably limited by the self-resonance of the cap.

Comment: Bypass BOTH leads of the thermocouple to Analog GND. This reduces the need for the Interface to handle large RF and large spike energy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference junction then you could use a scheme like this.

[image]

If it's high frequency noise (+100Mhz rectifying at the amplifier) you might want to try simply adding a clamp on ferrite on the cable or wrapping the thermocouple cable a few times around a ferrite core if you have one lying around. Make sure the thermocouple wire is not making a loop and twist it if its long.

Another option would be to filter the output of the MAX6675 and add a passive or active low pass filter

Comment: All thermocouple electronics has a (usually) pair of reference junctions whether you want them or not. Specifically they are the points where thermocouple alloy is connected to copper. If it's an ISA type T thermocouple then there is only the Constantan-copper junction.