# Does the AD8495 thermocouple amplifier allow for grounded thermocouple probes?

Tags: measurement, temperature, thermocouple

I recently purchased a [MAX31856](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31856.pdf) thermocouple-to-digital chip for a project. However, I discovered that the chip does not support grounded thermocouples. I am looking for an alternative and the [AD8495](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8494_8495_8496_8497.pdf) appears to be the only similar option. However, I cannot tell from the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8494_8495_8496_8497.pdf) whether it supports grounded thermocouple probes. How can I tell?

Comment: somewhat related [thread about MAX31856](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/101780/7036)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it.

In the 1st paragraph at pg 12 it tells how the IC deals with the problems coming from single-ended (i.e. grounded one end) TC usage.

The last sentence of that paragraph is the answer.

> The excellent common-mode rejection of the AD849x prevents variations in ground potential and other common-mode noise from affecting the measurement.