# How can I tell from a datasheet if a thermocouple amplifier IC will work with a grounded thermocouple?

Tags: measurement, datasheet, thermocouple

There are several different solution available for thermocouple amplification such as the [MAX31856](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31856.pdf), [AD8495](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8494_8495_8496_8497.pdf), and [LTC2983](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2983fc.pdf). Some of these support grounded thermocouples (AD8495) and some don't (MAX31856). This is not explicitly stated in the datasheets. How can I tell? My best guess is that I needs to look for a common-mode voltage rejection down to 0V. Is this correct?

Below is a picture of a "grounded thermocouple" configuration.
[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but related: [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/351355/7036) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101770/7036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you look for this (MAXIM part): -

```
Input Common-Mode Range 0.5 to 1.4 V
```

It doesn't go down to (or below) 0 volts hence it's no good for a ground connected TC.

The AD part says this: -

```
Input Voltage Range −VS – 0.2 to  +VS – 1.6
```

And this would be suitable to go 0.2 volts below the negative rail on the chip.

And for the LT part it says a similar story: -

```
Common Mode Input Range  –0.05 to VDD – 0.3
```

So you have: -

- Input Common-Mode Range
- Input Voltage Range
- Common Mode Input Range

As the main phrases to look for when choosing a chip that can handle grounded TC inputs.